# Is it possible to do sub-query join using ServiceStack's OrmLite?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Is it possible to do sub-query join using ServiceStack's OrmLite?

Something like this?

```
var q = Db.From<Customer>()
    .Join<Customer, subq>((c, subq) => c.CustomerID == subq.CustomerID)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no Typed API support for joining on a sub select but you can use a `CustomJoin` to do this, e.g:

```
var q = Db.From<Customer>()
    .CustomJoin("INNER JOIN (SELECT Id FROM ...) sub ON sub.Id = Customer.Id")
```

Comment: A couple of comments: 1) I couldn't find "CustomJoin" anywhere in the documentation. 2) It would be great to have alias for the first "Customer" in Db.From<Customer>() but it is not critical.

As always, thank you very much!