# Nested queries in ORMLite c#

Tags: c#, mysql, ormlite-servicestack

I was wondering about doing nested queries using `ORMLite`.
I need it to reduce the cardinality of a table in order to have a lighter join.

Basically, I'd need something to build the following `SQL statement`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_2
JOIN  (SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 WHERE <conditions>) ON <blah blah>
WHERE <blah blah>
```

I searched the documentation but I couldn't find anything using the "nested" keyword... As for now I could only think to do 2 queries and join them in my application, but I think it's not a viable way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44899741/is-it-possible-to-do-sub-query-join-using-servicestacks-ormlite